# How to extract sublists from a string in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have the following string:
List =[[1], ['apple', 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

How can I extract the sub-lists as following:
s1 = [1]
s2 = ['apple', 2]
...
s7 = [7]
?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi. You say "lists to strings". Do you actually want the variables s1...s7 to have string values? Also, do you need actual variables? Do you have multiple lists of various sizes, or just the one list?

Comment: I am sorry, I have to correct my question. The original list (here List) is a string so s1=List[0] gives me '['. Actually I want to convert this string to 7 lists.

Comment: See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create 7 variables named `s1` through `s7`, the most straightforward way is to do direct assignment.

```
s1 = List[0]
S2 = List[1]
...
S7 = List[6]
```

A second approach is to put all the assignments on one line and let python unpack the list, as described by @Lafada.

A third approach is to use `exec`, which may be more scalable for larger numbers of variables, although the value of all these separate names instead of the original list is not clear to me.

```
L = [[1], ['apple', 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

for i in xrange(7):
  exec("s%d = L[%d]" % ((i+1), i))
```

---

**Update**: Based on OP's comment, he is starting with a string. Each of these approaches can be used, after we first convert the string to a list using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

```
import ast

List = "[[1], ['apple', 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]"
L = ast.literal_eval(List)
```

Comment: I am sorry, I have to correct my question. The original list (here List) is a string so s1=List[0] gives me '['. Actually I want to convert this string to 7 lists.

Comment: @PouyaKh please [edit] your question to clarify what you want

Answer (score 4):

You have to use unpacking

```
>>> L = [[1], ['apple', 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
>>> s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7 = L
>>> s1
[1]
>>> s2
['apple', 2]
>>> s7
[7]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I have to correct my question. The original list (here List) is a string so s1=List[0] gives me '['. Actually I want to convert this string to 7 lists.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you could try the below.

```
s = []
s[:7] = List
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
List=[[1], ['apple', 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

output=""
for list_index in range(len(List)):
    output+="s%s = %s "%(list_index,List[list_index])


print output
```